# Are these the smallest Poulet-numbers above $10^{16}$ and $10^{17}\ \ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

A Poulet-number is a composite positive integer $\ N>1\ $ satisfying the condition $$2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$$ The numbers $$10^{16}+8\ 663\ 854\ 653$$ and $$10^{17}+209\ 045\ 665\ 633$$ are Poulet-numbers.

> Are the numbers the smallest Poulet-numbers above $10^{16}$ and $10^{17}$ respectively ?

How can I search the smallest Poulet number above a given number efficiently ?

Comment: Are you looking for a code that does it? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Yes, but not a code using brute force. The algorithm should be considerably faster (if such an algorithm is known/actually exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tabulation of all the Poulet numbers less than $2^{64}(\approx1.8447\times10^{19})$ can be found [here](http://www.janfeitsma.nl/math/psp2/index). There we find that the answer to your first question is *no*:

Your number $10^{16}+\hbox{8 663 854 653}$ is the *third* Poulet number beyond $10^{16}$; the first two are $10^{16}$ plus $\hbox{6 286 491 369}$ and $\hbox{8 250 001 701}$, respectively.

And your Poulet number $10^{17}+\hbox{209 045 665 633}$ is in fact the eighth Poulet number beyond $10^{17}$.  The first seven are $$10^{17}+(10\ 102\ 756\ 401,
56\ 076\ 920\ 001,116\ 526\ 957\ 249,139\ 941\ 938\ 721,150\ 553\ 089\ 531,
157\ 387\ 600\ 201, \rm{and}\ 174\ 032\ 555\ 661),$$ respectively.

Comment: I did not expect that the list of Poulet-numbers upto $2^{64}$ has actually been published. (+1)

Comment: Were you able to download and make use of the tabular data?  The data files are rather large; for my own use I downloaded and converted to native binary format on my computer, so that I could load and search more efficiently.  Not sure if you've explored completely Jan Feitsma's website: you might find the table of Poulet no, summary statistics (http://www.janfeitsma.nl/math/psp2/statistics) to be particularly useful.